# Date from mysql column changed after sending to front-end

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a booking table. When I select some bookings of user `SELECT * FROM booking WHERE guestId='3';` I've got:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+--------+---------+
| bookingId | startDate  | endDate    | roomId | guestId |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------+---------+
|         3 | 2016-04-10 | 2016-04-22 |      2 |       3 |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------+---------+
```

After, I send my data to front-end:

```
function getGuestHistory(id, res){
  dbHandler.query(`SELECT * FROM booking WHERE guestId='${id}';`, function(err, rows) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(!err ? rows : `error: ${err}`));
  });
}
```

And now in front-end, when I print it `console.log(res)` my response is different:

```
[Object]
0: Object
bookingId: 3
endDate: "2016-04-21T21:00:00.000Z"
guestId: 3
roomId: 2
startDate: "2016-04-09T21:00:00.000Z"
```

Look, `startDate` and `endDate` was changed. For example, `startDate` from DB `2016-04-10` now is `2016-04-09`. Why the date is changed and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's changing from the server's timezone to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Check the timezone settings in your database and on your server. These probably don't match.

The server converts the data from what is stored in the database, to what the server recognizes as it's own timezone.

Comment: That's happened because `JSON.stringify` use `toJSON method` that a built-in member of the `Date` object. It returns an ISO-formatted date string for the UTC time zone.